# database table design and relationship complexity

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relationship

Could someone suggest the best design for the following scenario?
I have a database in which there is a table called City. This table has the following fields:

- City id (Primary key)
- City Name
- State Id (which is linked to the State table)

My problem is I have 10 cities with the same name in one state. What will be the best design so I can represent one city name per id?

Comment: `one city name per id?` .. what do you mean?  You already have the tables you need to do this.. the state_id column in your city table will work to connect the two.  Not sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: `10 cities with same name in One state` does this thing really exists?

Comment: New York has 3 Greenvilles, 2 Franklins, 2 Miltons and 2 Riversides. In fact, there's at least 1 Greenville in every state, except Washington and South Dakota! I'll get my coat.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter that they have the same City Name, as long as they have different City Ids.

Just make sure to set the CityId as primary key in the City table. Also, it would be useful to make it an identity autoincrement column, so that it is inserted automatically and will always be unique.

Same goes for StateId in the State table.
Also, if you use a visual management tool for the database, make sure to set the foreign key relationship between the two tables:
FK_State.StateId_City.StateId.